# CakePHP 2 - manual login not adding to session

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to CakePHP and trying to get my head round register / login, Im using cakephp 2.0

If i create a user using a register controller function and then login seperately the session (*$this-Auth-user()*) contains all the Model values i expect.

If i follow the cakephp 2.0 book example and manually login during the register then I *do* get logged in but *$this->Auth->user()* only contains the fields from the register form not the User Model. (ie. its missing my Model fields "created", "full name" etc but includes "password" and "passwordconfirm" both unencrypted)

Am i missing something here?

Login Action:

```
public function login(){
if($this->request->is('post')){
    if($this->Auth->login()){
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Username or Password.'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
}
}
```

Register Action (with auto login):

```
public function register(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->User->create();
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){

            //Login automatically
            if($this->Auth->login($this->data['User'])){

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome to Test Site.'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Failed to login with new account.'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Register.ctp View

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'register'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password'));
echo $this->Form->input('passwordconfirm', array('label' => 'Confirm Password', 'type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Email (optional)'));
echo $this->Form->end('Join');
?>
```

Cheers for any help guys apologies this is a bit long!

---

EDIT:

Found a workaround! 
Looks like $this->Auth->login($this->data['User']) was failing to AuthComponent::identify() my User so i changed it for the following 3 lines:

```
$LoggedInID = $this->User->field('id', array('username' => $this->Auth->user('username')));
$user = $this->User->read(null, $LoggedInID);
$this->Auth->login($user);
```

and this works a treat.

Edit: You can also just use the return value of save():

```
        if($user = $this->User->save($this->request->data)){

            //Login automatically
            if($this->Auth->login($user)){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
if($this->Auth->login($this->data['User'])){
```

to

```
if($this->Auth->login()){
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the value of "session.cookie_domain" to my domain name in PHP.ini.

```
session.cookie_domain = my.domain.com
```

Now it works perfectly.

Session settings of core.php is as follows

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'     
));
```